Metropolis-Hastings algorithm in low dimension
In the final lecture of my statistical mechanics course, the professor introduced us as a bonus to the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. Given an unknown probability density $p(x)$ but some $f(x) \propto p(x)$, the algorithm can sample from $p(x)$.
My question is - isn't it way simpler to numerically integrate over $f(x)$ and sample
$$
f(x) / \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x')\mathrm{d}x'
$$
I understand that in higher dimensions integrating is hard so the algorithm is useful there, but is there any use in 1D as well (as my professor displayed it in the lectures)?

Why do you think $f$ is integrable?  (Equivalently, why do you think your favorite numerical integration technique converges for all $f$ of interest?)

A legitimate point. I don't know in which cases $f$ would be like this but in those specific ones I guess Metropolis-Hastings will succeed while other methods I can think of will fail.
